# Finding the time complexity of code

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Given is an infinite sorted array containing only numbers 0 and 1. Find the transition point efficiently.

For example : 00000000000111111111111111

Output : 11 which is the index where the transition occurs

I have coded a solution for this ignoring some edge cases.

```
int findTransition(int start)
{
  int i;
  if(a[start]==1)return start;
  for(i=1;;i*=2)
  {  
    //assume that this condition will be true for some index
    if(a[start+i]==1)break;
  }
  if(i==1)return start+1;
  return findTransition(start+(i/2));
}
```

I am not really sure about the time complexity of this solution here. Can someone please help me in figuring this out?

Is it O(log(N))?

Comment: If you're saying your array is infinite then `N` is infinite, and so your theoretical complexity is infinite too. Perhaps you should constrain your problem to a reasonable/realistic boundary...

Comment: That's how it was put up when I myself came across the question. Infinite as a concept. So, lets say a very big N. Or, lets say a[start+i]==1 will be true at some finite N.

Comment: What is the complexity if the transition will never occur ?

Comment: You can construct a simple algorithm for this by finding a `pos` with `1` through doubling `i`, and then running a binary search for the transition point from `pos/2` to `pos`.

Comment: If it is just large, use the binary search to find it.

Comment: No. We don't know about N here. Anyways, my concern here is to find the time complexity of this code.

Comment: @cerkiewny Use binary search to find what?

Comment: After first iteration you just do linear search with recursion and if you have static length(probably you will have) it can cause infinite loop.Worst case: O(n) Best case :O(1) Avg case:O(n).Linear search probably will do better.(after first iteration you send start+i/2 , then you start loop with start+(i/2)+1 then multiply 2*start+i+2 it is of course equal 1 you shoudn't recursive function for just check +1.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let n be position of transition point

This block

```
for(i=1;;i*=2)
  {  
    //assume that this condition will be true for some index
    if(a[start+i]==1)break;
  }
```

works for log2(n)

So we have

```
T(n) = log2(n) + T(n/2)
T(n) = log2(n) + log2(n/2) + T(n/4) = log2(n) + (log2(n) - 1) + (log2(n) - 2)... 
T(n) = log2(n) * (log2(n) + 1) / 2
```

So there is O(log(n)^2) complexity (for worst case)

Note: you can use usual binary search instead of recursion call, then you will have log2(n) + log2(n/2) just O(log(n)) granted.

Comment: Instead of the recursion call, if I do binary search for 1, it wont necessarily give the index of the first 1.

Comment: I mean binary search for transition point. You check midpoint and if it 1 recursively check left half, else check right half, until you will converge to the point. You can use it after you get some non infinite range to search.